# How to properly mock partially class with params in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a service called `GenerateReportService` in which I need to mock one method `generatePdf`. The problem is that I need to check the params which will be received in this method after others methods run. Because of different params `generatePdf` is not mocked.

```
$this->partialMock(GenerateReportService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();

    $packages = Package::with([
        'type',
        'details',
    ])->latest()->get();

    $mock->shouldReceive('generatePdf')->with(
        '/reports/packages',
        'packages',
        'pdf.reports.packages',
        [$packages, 40],
        false
    )->andReturn(redirect()->to('/'))->once();
});
```

I added `exit` to `generatePdf` and it always stops. If I remove params like this `$mock->shouldReceive('generatePdf')->once()->andReturn(redirect()->to('/'));` it works fine, but I need to check the incoming params. So the problem is in params - i understand that they differs and I need that test would fail if params are different.

Comment: You need to share the error or what is happening... What do you mean with "_I added `exit`_", what `exit`? Where exactly? and know that, once you remove the params (you remove `with`) you are altering the order of execution moving `->once()` BEFORE `->andReturn`. I did have issues where tests were not passing if I had `->once` after `return`, and they were passing if I had it before (or the other way around), it does matter here. Maybe, you want to use a [`spy`](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/spies.html) instead? Do you care if the method is run or not?